# Is there a way to remove Masonry for permalink pages

Tags: html, tumblr, jquery-masonry

Using Masonry on the index page works out fine,

but when I try to put stuff in a permalink - it treats every {block} like a Masonry column

ie http://wecantstophere.tumblr.com/post/123199045

code here - http://pastebin.com/9yZP4Jmd

although perhaps this might be most useful

```
a.left, a.right, .date, .notes,{

float:left;
}
```

and

```
{block:PermalinkPage}

<div class="wrapper">                 

{block:PermalinkPagination}
    {block:PreviousPost}
    <div class="pagination">
        <a href="{PreviousPost}" class="left">Previous Post</a>
    </div>
    {/block:PreviousPost}
    {block:NextPost}
    <div class="pagination">
        <a href="{NextPost}" class="right">Next Post</a>
    </div>
   {/block:NextPost}
{block:PermalinkPagination}
    {block:Date}
         <div class="date">{DayOfMonthWithZero}.{MonthNumberWithZero}.{ShortYear}</div>
    {/block:Date}

    {block:PostNotes}
       <div class="notes">{PostNotes}</div>
    {/block:PostNotes}

</div>

{/block:PermalinkPage}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right before you start your Masonry and Infinite Scroll code put

```
{block:IndexPage}
```

...then right after the script tag put

```
{/block:IndexPage}
```

That will make that code *only* run on your home page (and I believe tag pages as well).

Comment: yes! that's great.

although - it's started to add a weird flickr (background loading images) is that related?

Comment: That's likely a flash of the posts before Masonry puts them into position. I'd start with all the posts having an opacity of 0, then when Masonry finishes you can animate the opacity back to 1.

Comment: oh. i have that already, i think - it's  >[this bit](http://pastebin.com/Kn1vbQQr)< , right?